# Procedure for laboratory synthesis of tertiary amines

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis, amines

I am having difficulty finding a procedure for making tertiary amines in the lab, any is fine but I am specifically interested in tributylamine.

Comment: Best way of doing it is by reductive amination between dibutylamine and butanal. Sodium Triacetoxyborohydride is a good reducing agent for this, can be done in dichloromethane. See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo960057x   Tributylamine is widely commercially available.

Comment: Do you have access to database searches eg SciFinder, Reaxys? If you do, you should learn to use these.

Comment: Check the chemical inventory of your group / department / shop; a purchase of $\ce{NBu3}$ may be cheaper or / and faster than running a synthesis by your own.  Equally, _for learning_, consider the relevant entries on [organic-chemistry.org](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1N/amines/reductiveamination.shtm) for that they set a reaction into context of application / contemporary literature references.  With some names / name reactions retained, you will find your way through the general entry [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/), too.